# Specify columns in empty IQueryable in WCF Data Service?

Tags: excel, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a [DataService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646779(v=vs.113).aspx) with the following queryable:

```
public IQueryable<MyData> MyDataList => myDataList.AsQueryable();
```

I connect to this data service in `Excel 2016`. Everything works, but when the list is **empty** I get the following error message.

```
 The query did not run or the Data Model could not be accessed.
 Here's the error message we got:

 An Evaluate statement cannot return a table without columns
```

It seems the client (Excel) needs an object to successfully determine the columns. Why? **Is it possible to tell the client about the columns without the need for an object?**

Comment: reproduced. is [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6836d802-1099-4908-9ba6-0cb6fd8f8854/powerpivot-empty-odata-feed-no-column-definitions?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel) related?

Comment: Looks like the same issue. Some kind of metadata is indeed needed to successfully populate the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you check the resulted query first to see if it contains anything and return the actual data or a default one?

```
  var defaultList = new List<MyData>();

public IQueryable<MyData> MyDataList = (myDataList.Any())?myDataList.AsQueryable():defaultList.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Interesting idea; i fear it will not make a difference on the receiving end, let me check

Comment: no it behaves exactly the same (given that `myDataList` is no different from a new instance of `List<MyData>` in the empty case).

Comment: You need to add at least one object to the list. It's a weakness in the protocol, I guess.

Comment: if it is, its designer must be related to the guy who decided that unchecked checkboxes would just add bloat to a http postback.